# Cast a set of pointers to a base class to a set of pointers to its templated derived class

Tags: c++, casting, derived-class

I want to store items in some kind of custom in-memory database, classified by their type.

To do it, I want to use a map whose key is the type_index of the value being stored, and whose value is a std::set of a templated child class which stores the value being stored. It might be simpler to ilustrate than to enunciate:

My base class is called `ItemBase`.

The child class is like this:

```
template<class T>
class Item : public ItemBase {

    // ...
    T stored_item;  
    // ...

};
```

And my `class Database` has the following:

```
typedef std::set<ItemBase*> ItemList;

template <typename T>
using DefinedItemList = std::set<Item<T>*>;

typedef std::unordered_map<std::type_index, ItemList> MapOfItemLists;

// ...

MapOfItemLists itemsByType;
```

When saving an item, I store it with this function:

```
template<typename T> Item<T>* Database::add_item(T item) {

    Item<T>* pItem = new Item<T>(item,this);

    if(!item_type_exists(typeid(T)))
        itemsByType[typeid(T)] = ItemList();

    itemsByType[typeid(T)].insert(pItem);

    return pItem;
}
```

That said, the problem I'm having is when trying to retrieve a list for a concrete type, with the original templated child class type.

As the objects can accept any type, I can't predefine the types, so I save them in sets of `ItemBase*`. But how to recover the sets of `Item<T>*` ?

I tried doing a cast like this:

```
ItemList ret = itemsByType.find(type_index)->second;
return dynamic_cast<DefinedItemList<T>&>(ret);
```

But that gave me this error:

```
 error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘ret’ (of type ‘ItemList {aka class std::set<ItemBase*>}’) to type ‘DefinedItemList<int>& {aka class std::set<Item<int>*, std::less<Item<int>*>, std::allocator<Item<int>*> >&}’ (source type is not polymorphic)
```

But if I am not wrong, `ItemBase` is polymorphic:

```
class ItemBase {
public:
    virtual ~ItemBase() = 0;

};
inline ItemBase::~ItemBase() {}
```

Comment: `ItemBase` is polymorphic. But `ItemList` is not. `ret` is an `ItemList`.

Comment: You are right. So is there a better solution than to create a new std::set casting item per item?